# Enlarging bitmap in c

Tags: c

The following code takes in a bmp and enlarges it, rotates it or flips it. Everything is working properly except when i call the enlarge command line. the pictures comes up but it does not look any bigger.

This is the enlarge funtions:

```
int enlarge(PIXEL* original, int rows, int cols, int scale,
            PIXEL** new, int* newrows, int* newcols)
{
        int row, col, i, j;
        if((rows<=0)|| (cols<=0))
        {
                return -1;
        }

        *newrows=rows * scale;
        *newcols=cols * scale;

        *new=(PIXEL*)malloc((scale*rows)*(scale*cols)*sizeof(PIXEL));

        for(row=0;row<rows;row++)
        {
                for(col=0;col<cols;col++)
                {
                        PIXEL *o=original + row*cols +col;
                        for(j=0; j<scale;j++)
                        {
                                for(i=0; i<scale;i++)
                                {
                                PIXEL *n=(*new)+(row*scale+i)*(*newcols)+(col*scale+j);
                                *n=*o;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

  /* THIS IS THE METHOD THAT YOU SHOULD WRITE */
  return 0;
}
```

and this is the main function:

```
int degree, scale;
int is_rotate=0, is_scale=0, is_flip=0;
char *inputFile=NULL, *outputFile=NULL;

int r, c, check;
PIXEL *b, *nb;
int nr,nc;
int error;

//readFile("example.bmp",&r,&c,&b);
while((check=getopt(argc,argv,"s:r:o:f")) != -1)
{
switch (check)
{
        case 's':
        is_scale=is_scale+1;
        //enlarge(nb,nr,nc,optarg,&nb,&nr,&nc);
        scale=atoi(optarg);
        if(is_scale==2)
        {
                printf("bmptool: -s: scale can only be called once in commmand line");
                error=1;
        }
        if(scale<0)
        {
                printf("bmptool: -s : the scale must be a positive integer");
                error=1;
        }
        //printf("This is working s");
        break;


        case 'r':
        is_rotate= is_rotate+1;
        //rotate(b,r,c,optarg,&b,&r,&c);
        degree=atoi(optarg);
        if(is_rotate==2)
        {
                printf("bmptool: -r: rotation  can only be called once in commmand line");
                error=1;
        }
        if(degree%90 != 0)
        {
                printf("bmptool: -r: the degree of rotation must be a multiple of 90");
                error=1;
        }
        //printf("this is working r");
        break;

        case 'f':
        is_flip=is_flip+1;
        if(is_flip==2)
 {
                printf("bmptool: -f: flip can only be called once in command line");
        }
        break;


        case 'o':
        outputFile=(optarg);
        //printf(outputFile);
        //readFile(outputFile,&r,&c,&b);
        break;

}
}

if(error==1)
{
        return 0;
}

if(is_rotate==0 && is_scale==1 && is_flip==0)
{
        enlarge(nb,nr,nc,scale,&nb,&nr,&nc);
        writeFile(inputFile,r,c,b);
}
```

I only added the if statement that contains the enlarge. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, at least partly because PIXEL is not defined, and neither is main.  It'll be easier for us to help if you give us something that compiles, or if not, doesn't compile because of the problem you want addressed.

Comment: Have you updated the bitmap header with the new dimensions etc?

Comment: In `enlarge(nb,nr,nc,scale,&nb,&nr,&nc);` did you intend to pass `nb` for both the `original` and the `new` arguments? Shouldn't you have passed `b` for `new`, since that is what you next pass to `writeFile`? And did you intend to pass `nr` and `nc` (the new dimensions), as the original dimensions, instead of `r` and `c`?

Comment: it does compile. Everything works fine, the picture just comes out as the original 512x512 dimensions. I tried your solution wv but it comes out the same i did enlarge(nb,nr,nc,scale,&b,&r,&c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int enlarge(PIXEL* original, int rows, int cols, float scale,
        PIXEL** enlarged, int* newrows, int* newcols)
{
    int row, col;
    if((rows<=0)|| (cols<=0))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    (*newrows)=(int)((float)rows * scale);
    (*newcols)=(int)((float)cols * scale);

    *enlarged=(PIXEL*)malloc((*newrows)*(*newcols)*sizeof(PIXEL));

    for(row=0;row<(*newrows);row++)
    {
            for(col=0;col<(*newcols);col++)
            {
                     (*enlarged)[row * (*newcols) + col] = original[(row * rows / (*newrows))  * cols + col * cols / (*newcols)];
            }
    }

/* THIS IS THE METHOD THAT YOU SHOULD WRITE */
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: i change scale type to float in order to you could scale in any factor, but you could change to int with any problem

You must pass newrows and newcols by ref (not pointer)

**EDIT**: function usage

```
    scale = 2.0f;
    readFile("example.bmp",&r,&c,&b);
    enlarge(b,r,c,scale,&nb,&nr,&nc);
    writeFile("enlarge.bmp",nr,nc,nb);
    free(nb);
```

Comment: when i write it out using writeFile(inputFile,r,c,nb) the images comes up but the dimensions are the same

Comment: Check function usage added in answer, i think you are calling/using function "enlarge" in a wrong way. NOTE 1: i dont know how your readFile & writeFile functions works. NOTE 2: you must handle bmp details in your readFile & writeFile methods

Comment: I dont know your PIXEL definition, i assume operator = in PIXEL do what is spected

Comment: it's telling me that im missing a ',', or ';' between int and &

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standard Windows bitmap, then `newrows` must be of a scanline size. A bitmap image consists of scanlines. A scanline consists of pixels. A pixel consists of one or more components (colors).

A scanline must be a multiple of 4 bytes. So after the last component of the last pixel of a scanline, there may follow some unused bytes.

So your scaled bitmap must have scanlines of the appropriate size. See also
[Dealing with padding in a BMP file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261768/dealing-with-padding-in-a-bmp-file-in-c/36262866#36262866) of how to calculate scanline sizes and iterate over an image.

Note also that if you just "scale" with an integer, you can scale 1, 2, 3... integer times (100%, 200%,...). Scaling with non-integers requires smearing the pixels out over the new width and hight. Numerous algorithms and ready-to-use code are available on the internet.