# Bitmap loader not displaying color properly

Tags: c, bitmap, bitmapdata

I need to convert bitmap images to textures.So for that i am writing c code for parsing bitmap.I am able to parse bitmap rgb data and display it.But color is not coming properly.
Its 32bit image.(ARGB)

```
int pixels = width * height * 4;
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[pixels];
const int row = width * 4;
const int colomn = height;
unsigned char* datarow = new unsigned char[row];
unsigned char data1[pixels];
#if 1
fseek(f, 54,SEEK_SET);
fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), pixels, f);

 fclose(file);
#endif
for(int i = 0; i < colomn; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < row; j++)
    {
            data1[j+i*row] = data[j+((colomn-i)*row)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably the so-maniest who forgets that an image consist of scanlines and that scanlines are 32-bit alligned. So your simple row/column calculation doesn't work.

See [Dealing with padding in a BMP file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261768/dealing-with-padding-in-a-bmp-file-in-c/36262866#36262866) for how to work with scanlines.