# C: grayscale bmp to char array and back

Tags: c, image, bitmap

I'm working on a simple program that is supposed to store a grayscale 24-bit bmp to an array, manipulate the array and then create another 24-bit bmp from the array. The image is guaranteed to be a square. The program works as intended for images of sizes 125x125 and smaller, but outputs garbage for larger images and I can't figure out why. The code and the source image follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char *read_bmp(char *fname, int size, unsigned char* header, unsigned char* img){
  FILE *source = fopen(fname, "r");
  for(int i = 0; i < 54; i++){
    header[i] = fgetc(source);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < size*size; i++){
    //need only every third byte
    img[i] = fgetc(source);
    fgetc(source);
    fgetc(source);
  } 
  fclose(source);
}

void write_bmp(char *fname, int size, unsigned char* header, unsigned char* img){
  FILE *dest = fopen(fname, "w");
  for(int i = 0; i < 54; i++){
    fputc(header[i], dest);
  } 
  for(int i = 0; i < size*size; i++){
    //need to tripple every byte
    fputc(img[i], dest);
    fputc(img[i], dest);
    fputc(img[i], dest);
  }   
  fclose(dest);
}

int main(){
  int size = 126; //size is set manually to the size of the image
  unsigned char header[54];
  unsigned char img[size*size];
  read_bmp("source.bmp", size, header, img);
  write_bmp("dest.bmp", size, header, img);

  return 0;
}
```

[image: image used]

Comment: With BMP files, lines need to be padded to be a multiple of 4 (bytes).

Comment: More about padding BMP files _[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36262260/645128)_

Comment: You need to read the header and image sizes before setting the size of your buffers. You set the max size of your image buffer to 126x126 and you have problems with pictures bigger than 125x125.

Comment: @Ben oh no, I set the size manually and it corresponds to the size of the image, I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: in the first few fields of the image is the number of rows and number of columns in the image  Note: rows*columns is (usually) not enough room because part of the images structure is some 'pad' bytes at the end of each row, so the total length of the row is a a multiple of 4,  Also, near the top of the 'header' of the file is a pointer that indicates where the actual pixel data starts,  The code should be using such information to find the actual pixel data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is the alignment, as others have pointed out in the comments.  Each scanline is padded to a multiple of four bytes.  (In-memory scanlines must also begin on 4-byte boundaries, but that doesn't apply here.)  For smaller sizes, you were getting "lucky."

In a 24-bpp bitmap, a scanline takes `width * 3` bytes worth of data.  To compute how many padding bytes are needed, you first compute the "stride" and then subtract the amount of actual data.

```
int data_bytes_per_row = 3 * size;  // your width is size
int stride = (data_bytes_per_row + 3) / 4 * 4;
int padding_bytes = stride - data_bytes_per_row;
```

Now you can read the data like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
  for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
    // need only every third byte
    img[i++] = fgetc(source);
    fgetc(source);
    fgetc(source);
  }
  for (int pad = 0; pad < padding_bytes; ++pad) {
    fgetc(source);
  }
}
```

Likewise, for writing:

```
int i = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
  for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
    // need to triple every byte
    fputc(img[i], dest);
    fputc(img[i], dest);
    fputc(img[i], dest);
    ++i;
  }
  for (int pad = 0; pad < padding_bytes; ++pad) {
    fputc('\0', dest);
  }
}
```

Comment: @BarmakShemirani:  Fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented your solution, but the problem seems to run deeper than that. After some digging I've discovered that the problem is caused by 24-bit BMPs actually getting compressed. This would explain the luck with smaller images, since they're less likely to be compressed.

Answer (score 1):

24-bit bitmap has 3 bytes per pixel. So if your image has `size * size` pixels, then the total bytes is `size * size * 3`

Padding is also a major issue in 24-bit bitmaps. But if that were not an issue, you have to change your code as follows:

```
unsigned char img[size*size*3];
```

Read every 3rd bytes, so you have to read `i * 3`, instead of `i`

```
for(int i = 0; i < size * size; i++)
{
    img[i * 3] = (char)fgetc(source);
    fgetc(source);
    fgetc(source);
}
```

Write every 3rd bytes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size * size; i++)
{
    fputc(img[i * 3], dest);
    fputc(img[i * 3], dest);
    fputc(img[i * 3], dest);
}
```

To take padding in to consideration, use this code instead

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fin = fopen("source.bmp", "rb");
    FILE *fout = fopen("dest.bmp", "wb");

    char info[54] = { 0 };
    fread(info, sizeof(info), 1, fin);
    fwrite(info, sizeof(info), 1, fout);

    int width = *(int*)(info + 18);
    int height = *(int*)(info + 22);
    int bitcount = *(int*)(info + 28);
    if(memcmp(info, "BM", 2) != 0 || width < 1 || height < 1 || bitcount != 24)
        return 0;

    int stride = width * 3 + width % 4;
    char *buf = malloc(stride);
    for(int row = height - 1; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        fread(buf, 1, stride, fin);
        for(int col = 0; col < stride; col += 3)
        {
            unsigned char* p = (buf + col);
            unsigned char b = p[0];
            unsigned char g = p[1];
            unsigned char r = p[2];
            unsigned char gray = (unsigned char)(.3 * r + .6 * g + .1 * b);
            p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = gray;
        }
        fwrite(buf, 1, stride, fout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's pointless to make the array 3 times bigger, and then only use every third byte in the array.

Comment: @user3386109 24-bit bitmap has 3 bytes per pixel, even if those bytes are all the same. If padding was not required, you could save memory with `unsigned char img[size * size]`, I think that's what you mean. But that buffer cannot be used in any standard bitmap function. Also the asker is reading/writing one byte a time, so there is no point in allocating `size * size` bytes. The correct usage is `unsigned char `img[width_in_bytes * height]`

Comment: I don't think the goal is to use the array with a standard bitmap function.  The array is the internal format the OP wants for doing whatever manipulations to the data they want.  The reading and writing functions in the OP are attempting to translate between the internal format and the BMP format, and the fundamental problem is that the padding in the BMP format isn't account for.